# Python and Gekko optimization

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I'm not familiar with optimizations and I want to achieve a goal as following:

Suppose I have 3 lists of constants:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list_2 = [5, 8, 10, 11]
list_3 = [20, 27, 89, 100]
```

I want to find 3 indexes `i1, i2, i3`, corresponding to the 3 lists above, such that the sum will be minimized: `min(list_1[i1] + list_2[i2] + list_3[i3])`

subject to some constraints:

```
i1 >= 0
i2 >= 0
i3 >= 0
i1 + i2 + i3 == 4
64 * i1 + 72 * i2 + 74 * i3 >= 240
```

I tried to write it as:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

x_1_storage = m.Array(m.Const, 4)
x_1_values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
i = 0
for xi in x_1_storage:
    xi.value = x_1_values[i]
    i += 1

x_2_storage = m.Array(m.Const, 4)
x_2_values = [5, 8, 10, 11]
i = 0
for xi in x_2_storage:
    xi.value = x_2_values[i]
    i += 1

x_3_storage = m.Array(m.Const, 4)
x_3_values = [20, 27, 89, 100]
i = 0
for xi in x_3_storage:
    xi.value = x_3_values[i]
    i += 1


x,y,z = m.Array(m.Var,3,integer=True,lb=0) 
m.Minimize(x_1_storage[x.value.value] + x_2_storage[y.value.value] + x_3_storage[z.value.value])
m.Equations([x>=0,
             y>=0,
             z>=0,
             x+y+z==4,
             64*x + 72*y + 74*z >= 240])
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()
print('Objective: ', m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
print('x: ', x.value[0])
print('y: ', y.value[0])
print('z: ', z.value[0])
```

However, the objective value printed is 26, when the correct objective value should instead be 4 since `x_1_storage[4] = 4`. Somehow, the first element in each list gets added as the objective value. My impression is something is wrong with the way the objective is expressed:

```py
m.Minimize(x_1_storage[x.value.value] + x_2_storage[y.value.value] + x_3_storage[z.value.value])
```

However, I'm not quite sure what to do in this case. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.value` property is only for storing the initial guess value before `m.solve()` and for reporting the solution after the solve. These will be constant values in the optimization problem if they are used in the expressions.

The solution `i1=4` is incorrect because the index goes from `0` to `3`. Below is an alternative form that solves the problem. The cubic spline object `cspline` is used to relate the index decision variable to the `x_store` list value for the objective function.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=True)

# index decision variable
x = m.Array(m.Var,3,value=4,lb=0,ub=3,integer=True)
i1,i2,i3 = x

# cublic spline
ix = [0,1,2,3]
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list_2 = [5, 8, 10, 11]
list_3 = [20, 27, 89, 100]
y = m.Array(m.Var,3)
y1,y2,y3 = y
for i,iy in enumerate([list_1,list_2,list_3]):
    m.cspline(x[i],y[i],ix,iy,bound_x=True)

# constraints
m.Equations([i1+i2+i3==4,
             64 * i1 + 72 * i2 + 74 * i3 >= 240])
             
# objective
m.Minimize(y1+y2+y3)

# solve
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

# print solution
print(f'x: {x}')
print(f'y: {y}')
print(f'objective: {m.options.OBJFCNVAL}')
```

Solution:

```
x: [[3.0] [1.0] [0.0]]
y: [[4.0] [8.0] [20.0]]
objective: 32.0
```

If the index is allowed to be between 1 and 4, the solution `i1=4` is incorrect because of the constraint `i1+i2+i3=4` is infeasible if there are lower bounds of `i1>=1`, `i2>=1`, and `i3>=1`. If it is a 1-based index then `i2=0` and `i3=0` are not allowed.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# index decision variable
x = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=1,ub=4,integer=True)
i1,i2,i3 = x

# cublic spline
ix = [1,2,3,4]
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list_2 = [5, 8, 10, 11]
list_3 = [20, 27, 89, 100]
y = m.Array(m.Var,3)
y1,y2,y3 = y
for i,iy in enumerate([list_1,list_2,list_3]):
    m.cspline(x[i],y[i],ix,iy,bound_x=True)

# constraints
m.Equations([i1+i2+i3==4,
             64 * i1 + 72 * i2 + 74 * i3 >= 240])
             
# objective
m.Minimize(y1+y2+y3)

# solve
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

# print solution
print(f'x: {x}')
print(f'y: {y}')
print(f'objective: {m.options.OBJFCNVAL}')
```

The solution is:

```py
x: [[2.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
y: [[2.0] [5.0] [20.0]]
objective: 27.0
```